# Custom Collector Implementation for summing float java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I am trying to create a custom float addition similar to `Collectors.summingDouble()`.

But I am facing 2 issues and I am not sure about how to fix it.

1. `BiConsumer` - Line #27 - void methods cannot return a value
2. `Collectors.of` - Line#32 - The method of(Supplier, `BiConsumer<R,T>`, `BinaryOperator<R>`, Collector.Characteristics...) in the type Collector is not applicable for the 
   arguments (`Supplier<Float[]>`, `BiConsumer<Float,Employee>`, `BinaryOperator<Float>`)
   What needs to be done here for fixing the issue?

```
public class CustomCollector {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee e1=new Employee(1,"Tom",10.2f);
        Employee e2=new Employee(1,"Jack",10.4f);
        Employee e3=new Employee(1,"Harry",10.4f);
        ArrayList<Employee> lstEmployee=new ArrayList<Employee>();
        lstEmployee.add(e1);lstEmployee.add(e2);lstEmployee.add(e3);

/*  Implementation 1
 *  double totalSal=lstEmployee.stream().collect(Collectors.summingDouble(e->e.getSal()));
        System.out.println(totalSal);
*/  
        //Implementation 2
        Function<Employee,Float> fun=(e)->e.getSal();
        BiConsumer<Float,Employee> consumer=(val,e)->val+e.getSal();
        BinaryOperator<Float> operator=(val1,val2)->val1+val2;
        Supplier<Float[]> supplier=() -> new Float[2];

        float FtotalSal=lstEmployee.stream().collect(
                Collector.of(supplier,consumer,operator));
        System.out.println(FtotalSal);
    }

}

class Employee {
    int id;
    String name;
    float sal;
    // getters, setter, constructror
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems, you are confusing [Reduction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Reduction) with [Mutable Reduction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#MutableReduction).

Your functions, `(val, e) -> val + e.getSal()` and `(val1, val2) -> val1 + val2)`, are suitable for a Reduction operation, but not for `collect`. The supplier, producing a `Float[]` array of length two, doesn’t fit to it at all.

E.g., you can perform your operation using

```
float f = lstEmployee.stream().reduce(
    0F,
    (val, e) -> val + e.getSal(),
    (val1, val2) -> val1 + val2);
```

This bears some boxing overhead, as all intermediate sums are represented as `Float` objects.

You can avoid this using [Mutable Reduction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#MutableReduction), when you create a mutable container which is capable of holding a `float` value without boxing, i.e. `new float[1]`. Then, you have to supply functions accepting an array argument and changing the contained value. Since your intended result is a `float`, rather than an array, you further need a *finisher* to produce the final result.

```
float f = lstEmployee.stream().collect(
    Collector.of(
        () -> new float[1], // a container capable of holding one float
        (floatArray,e) -> floatArray[0] += e.getSal(), // add one element to the array
        (a1, a2) -> { a1[0] += a2[0]; return a1; }, // merge two arrays
        array -> array[0]) // extracting the final result value
    );
```

Of course, this is only for exercising, as you have already shown to know a simpler solution using builtin features.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Holger. reduction and collect were new terms for me.  Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 0):

If getting the sum is the focus. You could try something like below.

```
 float FtotalSal = (float) lstEmployee.stream().mapToDouble(e -> e.getSal()).sum();
```

Comment: How can i get the same using custom collector? I have already implemented and commented the logic being suggested. 
Its for practise purpose.